# Get index value during `formatlist`

Tags: terraform

I have a `null_resource` that runs a `remote-exec` provisioner in some servers and the servers are referenced via a list of IPs.

For each of these servers I need to generate a string in the following format:

```
"server.1=<IP 1> server.2=<IP 2> server.3=<IP 3>"
```

So that every server has a reference to the others.

My current string interpolation is something like this:

```
resource "null_resource" "provision" {
    count = <NUMBER OF SERVERS>
    ...
    provisioner "remote-exec" {
        inline = [
            "echo ${formatlist("server.%d=%s", count.index, public_ips)}"
        ]
    }
}
```

The problem is that `count.index` references `NUMBER OF SERVERS`, so it's constant for each run of `formatlist`, so my outputs are coming out like this:

```
"server.1=<IP 1> server.1=<IP 2> server.1=<IP 3>"
"server.2=<IP 1> server.2=<IP 2> server.2=<IP 3>"
"server.3=<IP 1> server.3=<IP 2> server.3=<IP 3>"
```

How can I generate this index properly?

I thought of something like a `range` function where I could pass a number and it would generate a list from 0 to that number, but I don't see anything like it in the [docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html).

**Edit:** 
Some information that I forgot to include in the original question:

My `public_ips` list is a simple list of strings like

```
["IP 1", "IP 2", "IP 3"]
```

I am using Terraform v0.10.6

Comment: So my question for you is, what you want to get?  Paste the result you need

Comment: @BMW I pasted the expected output near the beginning of question:

`"server.1=<IP 1> server.2=<IP 2> server.3=<IP 3>"`

That would be the same in all the servers.

Comment: How is the `public_ips` looks like? A list, such as `[ "IP 1", "IP 2", "IP 3" ]`?

Comment: Yes, it's a list just like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently impossible. Look here: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/2769

Comment: Looking forward for HCL2 :)